# How to check whether an EditText in Android has emoticon or not?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I need to check whether an edit text has some emoticon in it or not. I tried making a text watcher in which I checked whether an Image span is present but I am unable to get any results.

```
SpannableStringBuilder s = new SpannableStringBuilder(source.toString());
ImageSpan a[]= s.getSpans(0,s.length(), ImageSpan.class);

if(a.length!=0){
    Toast.makeText(NewEpisodeActivity.this, R.string.invalid_char, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do check in `afterTextChanged(Editable editable)` not in `onTextChanged()`

```
private TextWatcher textChangedListener = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        final ImageSpan[] itemSpans = editable.getSpans(0, editable.length(), ImageSpan.class);
        final boolean hasEmoticons = itemSpans != null && itemSpans.length > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take hasmap with emoticons code as key and emoticon image as value.
Now check for the text whether it is the emoticons code if yes then

```
s.setSpan(new ImageSpan(Context, Emoticons_Image, startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```